# cakephp User Login Redirect Without AppController

Tags: php, cakephp, app-config

I am trying to create an applciation in cakephp where I am allowing user registration and login system, but my AppController is somehow encryption and I don't know how to decrypt it.

Is that possible to redirect admin and user to their relevant pages without configuring AppControler (app_controler.php).

Thanks everyone for great help.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? Do you have a file called `AppController.php` or `app_controller.php` in your app/Controllers directory?

Comment: Yes @xgalvin

Actually file is app_controller.php and I came across that cakephp is licence (Commercial) version so it is not possible to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean AppController is encrypted?

To me, it looks like you are trying to by-pass a commercial product license.

Comment: HI @XuDing, Thanks for reply.
Yes! I want to bypass that commercial product. I need to add some lines of code in AppController, but for my case It is not possible.

Is there any way I can override it.